# NAV 2009 PO Integration

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, navision

I have no experience with NAV.

I have to move Purchase Order data from one system, to NAV2009.  I worked on the ETL part, and I have all the data to be moved to NAV ready.  How do I import it to NAV?

Answer (score 1):

This depends, of course, on where your data is stored and whether your license allows to write code / create new objects in NAV. But in any case, there are at least two tables that must be filled - "Purchase Header" and "Purchase Line". Probably, some other tables (like Document Dimension) might be required - depends on the data you need to transfer. It is not recommended to insert records directly into corresponding SQL Server tables, since there is a lot of C/AL code in NAV order tables that validates the data, so C/AL triggers must be executed.

This still leaves several options.

1. Write C/AL code that would read data from external source and insert records into purchase header and purchase line. This assumes that you have appropriate license permissions and some experience with NAV dev environment.
2. Create an XMLPort object if the data can be stored in XML format. Or a Dataport for csv-like files - this object is still available in 2009. Can be restricted by the license too. [About NAV XMLPort objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd338846.aspx) and [NAV Dataport objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd339001.aspx)
3. Publish purchase order pages as web services and insert records from a consuming application. [Registering and consuming a web service in NAV 2009](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd355316.aspx)